# How to create a measure that goes first through equipment and then sums it all

Tags: powerbi

I have a database that has some values as "Date", "StopedTime", "PlannedProductionQtt" and "PlannedProductionTime". These values are sorted by equipment, as the little example below.

[image: example 1]

What I need to do is divide PlannedProductionQtt by PlannedProductionTime and then multiply by StoppedTime. After this, I want to make a graph that shows it day by day.

At first I thought it was easy, made a new measure `PlannedProductionQtt/PlannedProductionTime = SUM(PlannedProductionQtt)/SUM(PlannedProductionTime)` (assume it worked without the table name).

And then I did another measure `Impact = SUM(StoppedTime)*PlannedProductionQtt/PlannedProductionTime`.

When I plotted a clustered column chart with this measure in values and a the day for the axis, at first I thought I had nailed it, but no. The BI summed all of PlannedProductionQtt and divided by the sum of all PlannedProductionTime for the day, and multiplied by the sum of the StoppedTime of that day.

Unfortunately, this gives me wrong results. So, what I need is a measure (or some measures) that would make it equipment by equipment and the sum it by day.

I don't want to make new tables or columns for theses calculations because I actually have 32 items of equipment, 3+ years of data, more than 1 classification of StoppedTime and the databases for PlannedProduction use more than one line per day per equipment.

To make it clear I added one column as Impact to show the difference.
[image: With impact]

So, if I sum the column Impact per day, I would have for day 1,2 and 3 the results 110725, 61273 and 220833.

However, if I sum first all the PlannedProductionQtt for day 1, divide it by the sum of PlannedProductionTime of day 1 and multiply it by the sum of StoppedTime of day 1 (which is how PowerBi is calculating) I will have 146497.

I inserted the difference in the table below to make the differences clear:
[image: Impacto desejado]

Comment: Look at SUMX it will work it out on a row by row them divide correctly

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have tried, but it was not wht I needed. Here is what I wrote.  `measure_name = CALCULATE( DIVIDE( SUMX( source_table,source_table[PlannedProductionQtt]), SUMX( source_table,source_table[PlannedProductionTime]),0)*SUMX(source_table,source_table[StoppedTime]))`

Comment: Sorry! I see I may have used it wrong! so here is the new try: `measure_name = SUMX(source_table,DIVIDE(source_table[PlannedProductionQtt],source_table[PlannedProductionTime],0) * SUM(source_table[StoppedTime])`                                                        This gave me a different answer (different values). Not exactly what I had before. But I will investigate more to see if they are what I look for. Will be back in some hours. Thanks!

Comment: Okay, this was trully usefull! I now got another thing to solve. But this was it! Thank you!

Comment: Please do not add things like "SOLVED" to a question title. If you managed to solve your problem, **accept** the answer that helped you solve it (by clicking the check mark in front of that answer), or if no answer helped you, post your own answer with the solution, and accept it after the timeout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jon suggested in a comment, here is what solved my needs:

`measure_name = SUMX( source_table , DIVIDE ( source_table[PlannedProductionQtt] , source_table[PlannedProductionTime] , 0 ) ) * SUM( source_table[StoppedTime] )`

Answer (score 0):

You have two different types of data you want to divide there, time and int, so you would probably need to unify that. Easiest way to do it would be from the Transform data panel, selecting the column and changing its
[format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aye3d.png)

The division is done fairly easily, can you try creating a new measure as follows

```
measure_name = CALCULATE(
                         DIVIDE(<source_table>[PlannedProductionQtt],
                                <source_table>[PlannedProductionTime],
                                0)    
                         * <source_table>[StoppedTime]
                        )
```

Then it's only a matter of using it as values in a graph and the 'Date' column in x axis.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I tested and it was not what I needed. I will try to explain it better, for that I will edit my question.